# How do developers fix bugs when compiling takes so long?

Tags: compiling

It takes so long to compile Bitcoin Core on my machine... I can't imagine trying to fix bugs like a missed semicolon and having to wait an hour for the compiler to finish before testing. Is this really what devs have to deal with? Or is there a way to just compile smaller units of the code and run it quickly over and over again until all the semi colons are fixed?

Comment: How long does it take to compile the *second* time you try?

Comment: If you modify a file and rerun `make`, it only compiles the section you touched. Also, you can run it as `make -j 2` to get it to run on two cores at once.

Answer (score 4):

Initial compiling of bitcoin-core can take a couple of minutes. If you have a multicore processor, you can use `make -j<cores+1>` to speed up compiling (parallel compiling).

Once bitcoin-core is compiled, a single semicolon change does (mostly) **not** require to recompile everything. You only compile the affected files (.cpp) again and do do the linking.

On most machines, compiling a simple change requires mostly less then 10 seconds.

Comment: In addition, if you install ccache, Bitcoin Core's build process will make use of it, preventing recompilation even when going back to an earlier version of the file you've already compiled before.

Comment: @PieterWuille and then you wait for the client to verify chain and sync before trying out your new expirimental OP code, etc.?

Comment: Verifying the chain is not nearly sufficient for a proposed consensus rule change (which a new opcode is). We usually demand extensive use cases, unit/RPC tests, many reviews, and IRC meeting/mailinglist discussion for something like that. For non-consensus changes, things are simpler.